# XOR for each two Char

Tags: vb.net

and first of all sorry for my english i will try be understandable ;o)

I have a textbox with value in it like: "577457747037375770" and so on, i want to XOR each value of them with "0x1b" how can i do that ?

Like "0x1b" XOR 57 ; "0x1b" XOR 74 ; "0x1b" XOR 87 and so on for all value in textbox.
I don't want to check if the value in the textbox is in the good format, i want just XOR them all.

Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you want to achieve :(. Seems like from the text box you will be taking first two characters from the string convert it into an integer and then do XOR on it !!

Is this what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you XOR'ing with hex 1B (decimal 27)???

```
    Dim testStr As String = "577457747037375770"

    For x As Integer = 0 To testStr.Length - 1 Step 2
        Dim charsAsInteger As Integer

        If Integer.TryParse(testStr.Substring(x, 2), charsAsInteger) Then
            Dim afterXOR As Integer = charsAsInteger Xor &H1B
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: exactly but i want to be able to XOR with different value, 1B decimal 27 is for this time, the value of 1b must be typed in an other textbox, i can change this value if i want to....